# allocating category to a comment pandas

Tags: pandas, nlp, multiclass-classification, categorization

My task is to allocate broad and fine category to the text I have in a pandas dataframe.

My df is something like this:

```
          Text  
     I like this pen
     this is the worst light bulb ever
     these pants fit me just fine
```

Desired output:

```
          Text                                Broad_cat                Fine_cat 
     I like this pen                         Stationary                  Pen
     this is the worst light bulb ever       Electrical                  light Bulb
     these pants fit me just fine            Clothing                    Pants
```

The text could be from any category, so I cant use a prepared dictionary. These are reviews that I can get from any source. I was hoping that there is an open source python package that can help me with the specific task of categorization of a comment. I already tried YAKE, RAKE, Summa and KeyBERT methods and while each of them are giving me key words, they dont always turn out to be the category. Is this even possible? Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have a list of allowed categories?

This a [multiclass classification problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification).

A fiddly approach is you embed the sentences into some sort of vector space then use a somethign like the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) to select the class and then train your model based on training data. [This post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/multiclass-text-classification-using-deep-learning-f25b4b1010e5) discusses this.

I think you might be more interested in [zero-shot text classification](https://towardsdatascience.com/zero-shot-text-classification-with-hugging-face-7f533ba83cd6). Hugging face has a pipeline (what of using models for certain tasks) [for this](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.ZeroShotClassificationPipeline) with the property `candidate_labels`. So you should be able to use this with an appropriate model and specify candidate labels... though the underlying model would have support this in some way, but presumably some do. [cross-encoder/nli-distilroberta-base](https://analyticsindiamag.com/a-complete-tutorial-on-zero-shot-text-classification/) appears to support this.

`

Comment: hi, I dont have a list of allowed categories, I would just have to classify any text I get. I will check the given links, thanks a lot for the guidance

Comment: "they dont always turn out to be the category." <- I wasn't sure what this means - what is necessary to be a category

Comment: I meant to say that sometimes when the comment contains the category word (like clothing, stationary, etc), these words are being picked up as key words by yake, rake, and keybert methods.

Comment: Is that bad? What do you want the categories to be?

Comment: yes. I want my texts categorized into "clothing, stationary, cosmetics, etc", but not always does the comment contain the word "clothing, stationary, etc". I was wondering if there is an open source python package that can help me with this. Or a suggestion as to how to handle this in a different way

Comment: So do you know all the items in the list "clothing, stationary, cosmetics"?

Comment: no, that is the problem. I am trying to build this for any comment I may be thrown. Thats why wondering if there is a package to help

Comment: So there are packages that will be do zero shot learning. But you don't seem to like the results... but you also can't fix the categories. I guess there might be some models that have been trained on a similar task. What do you want to be true about the categories?

Comment: sorry, I dont understnad "What do you want to be true about the categories?", could you please clarify?

Comment: So... you want to be able to generate a category for each piece of text. You don't have a list of these categories, but you are unhappy with the categories returned? Do you know what needs to be true about the categories - what is wrong with the bad categories?

Comment: no, I have not tried zero shot learning yet, but I tried YAKE, RAKE and KeyBERT and they only return key words, not necessarily categories

Comment: What's the difference between a category and a keyword for you? That keywords always come from wthinn a document.

Comment: yes, for example, if text says, 'these pants are too tight', key words would be 'pants', 'small' and category would be 'clothing'. Category is not necessarily stated in the text